# SSH connection via tunnel (relay)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, relay

I have `n` ssh clients that establish a connection to a SSH server via the following command

```
/usr/bin/ssh \
  -N \
  -i "/home/tunnel/.ssh/id_rsa" \
  -R "/home/tunnel/sockets/client_name.socket:127.0.0.1:22" \
  -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
  -p 443 "tunnel@tunnel.example.com"
```

I would like to connect to those clients from a machine that is not the SSH server itself, we currently do so by connecting to the tunnel SSH server first and then connecting to the remote clients from there.

Is there a way to do that directly? Some kind of special command to tell SSH what the ssh connection need to be done using another ssh connection

Comment: perhaps you're thinking of a ProxyJump